# Adwhirl ASIHttpRequest Crashing iPhone

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, adwhirl

I am using AdWhirl in my iphone app and I am displaying the adView in several different views. Each view has a different adView ivar. Problem is that when I am switching the views quickly, `ASIHttpRequest` within Adwhirl code tries to call the view after the view has been deallocted. I have tried setting the delegate to nil in my view but to no avail. Are there any other workarounds to cancel the AdWhirl `ASIHttpRequest` when the view is deallocated. In my view dealloc I am doing something like:

```
adView.delegate = nil;
adView = nil
```

where adView is an ivar declared like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AdWhirlView *adView;
```

## Crash Log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32ad5c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   SocialMashup                    0x0005503c -[ASIHTTPRequest requestReceivedResponseHeaders:] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:1954)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36387efc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
3   Foundation                      0x32cfe7a2 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 262
4   CoreFoundation                  0x363f1a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
5   CoreFoundation                  0x363f3758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
6   CoreFoundation                  0x363f44e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
7   CoreFoundation                  0x36384ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
8   CoreFoundation                  0x36384dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
9   GraphicsServices                0x30cdd418 GSEventRunModal + 108
10  GraphicsServices                0x30cdd4c4 GSEventRun + 56
11  UIKit                           0x3037cd62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
12  UIKit                           0x3037a800 UIApplicationMain + 664
13  ZFirewall.dylib                 0x013dcb24 0x13cd000 + 64292
14  SocialMashup                    0x000024ae main (main.m:17)
15  SocialMashup                    0x00002444 start + 32
```

Comment: self.adView.delegate = nil; and self.adView = nil; access it using property. Post crash logs

Comment: I added crash logs. Also what is the difference between self.adView.delegate = nil; and just adview.delegate=nil;

Comment: crashed because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS, set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES and start debugging. using self.adView.delegate = nil; you are accessing property where as adView.delegate = nil you are accessing instance variable (If you have instance variable in @interface AdWhirlView *adView; then its fine, but its recommended for readability to use self. when accessing through property that way its more obvious)

Comment: I'm trying to find where AdWhirl uses ASIHttpRequest specifically. Is this a part of the request AdWhirl is making for an ad or are you using ASIHttpRequest for something else?

Comment: I think ASIHttpRequest is used by AdWhirl internally to request ads asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure AdWhirl doesn't use `ASIHTTPRequest` at all.  Maybe a particular ad network you're using does, but the logs don't even seem to point to AdWhirl as the culprit.